# How to simulate multiple child elements with different values in the same Jmeter POST request body?

Tags: jmeter

The below request being the base request,

```
    [
    {
     "name": "Test1",
     "description": "testings",
    "unitname": simple,
    "ID": 02,
      "val": "item"
      },
     {
    "name": "Test2",
   "description": "testing",
    "unitname": simple3,
    "ID": 23,
    "val": "item"
    }
  ]
```

I want to simulate this with multiple (1000) 'child' sections like the below in a single JMeter request:
It should create 1000 data set(name,description,unitname,ID,val) with unique values and then post the request. Instead of manually creating multiple tags, can i automate it or create a script to generate this automatically ?

```
    [
    {
   "name": "Test1",
    "description": "testings",
    "unitname": simple,
     "ID": 02,
     "val": "item"
     },
      {
     "name": "Test2",
     "description": "testing",
      "unitname": simple3,
       "ID": 23,
       "val": "item"
     }

         {
         "name": "Test3",
             "description": "testing",
            "unitname": simple4,
            "ID": 23,
            "val": "item"
            }
       {
          "name": "Test4",
         "description": "testing",
         "unitname": simple6,
           "ID": 23,
           "val": "item"
             } 
           ]
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of your request where you need to send the generated JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
   import groovy.json.internal.LazyMap
   import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils

   def data = new ArrayList()

   1.upto(1000, {
       def entry = new LazyMap()
       entry.put('name', 'test' + it)
       entry.put('description', RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10))
       entry.put('unitname', 'simple')
       entry.put('ID', it)
       entry.put('val', 'item')
       data.add(entry)

   })

   def builder = new JsonBuilder()

   builder(
           data.collect {
               [
                       name        : it.get('name'),
                       descrtiption: it.get('description'),
                       unitname    : it.get('unitname'),
                       ID          : it.get('ID'),
                       val         : it.get('val')
               ]
           }
   )


   sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument("", builder.toPrettyString(), "")
   ```
3. Tick `Cache compiled script if available` box
4. Make sure `groovy` is selected in "Language" dropdown

That's it, the above script will generate a [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) and set it as the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler's body.

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Dmitri T. Can you tell me how do i set the response of the above JSON script in the POST request ?

Comment: I have created a JSR233 PreProcessor as suggested by you above, but the POST data in my HTTP Request is still blank in the 'View Results Tree'. Am i missing something? should i use the return from the groovyscript in the HTTP Request POST Data section?

Comment: I did take a look at your old post on how to use JSR Prepocessor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36444737/how-to-use-jsr-223-preprocessor-in-jmeter. This one works well.. but i'm unable to use the baove groovy script.. any help please? My HTTP POST request body shows blank data on the View Results Tree.

Comment: Corrected last couple of lines, kindly try again

Comment: one question, what does the variable 'it' refer to?  entry.put('name', 'test' + it)